# Python regular expression, looking for the end of the line or inverted commas

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to find in my file all the the comments as follow:

```
list = re.findall(("COMMENT\S+.WAIT\S+ := "), contents)

COMMENT[1].WAIT.1 := "WAIT REQUEST TO EAT"--->From the file
```

What I get  in my list `"COMMENT[1].WAIT.1 :="`

The problem is that I don´t know how to get all the chain because of if I add \D+ I would look until the next empty space and If I put a OR condition I get all the file but I just want this line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to process one line at a time, but your string contains the whole file?  What if you split the string on the newline character, to produce an array of lines, and then run each line through your regex?

Comment: The problems is that the pattern is in more places on the file as follow:

Fragment of the file

COMMENT[1].START := "DOOR CELL 1",
COMMENT[3].START := "DOOR CELL 3",
COMMENT[1].WAIT.1 := "WAIT TO ENTER 1",
COMMENT[2].WAIT.1 := "WAIT TO ENTER 2",
COMMENT[3].WAIT.3 := "WAIT TO ENTER 3",

So, is plenty of COMMENT[X].WAIT.X, then the plan is to get all the chain in a list with the function re.findall.

Comment: The list should be as follow:   In pos 0, COMMENT[1].WAIT.1 := "WAIT TO ENTER 1". In pos 1, COMMENT[3].WAIT.3 := "WAIT TO ENTER 3". Etc,

Comment: I want to process all the file once.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution:

re.findall(('COMMENT\S+.WAIT\S+ := .+"'), contents)